# My school is making everyone install SSL certificates and without it you cannot access the school network

Tags: certificates

[This](http://cert.n4l.co.nz/) is the certificate they are making everyone install.
Exactly what can they access using this and should I be concerned about my privacy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My school wifi asks to 'trust' a certificate on Iphone's, does it this allow them to view SSL traffic?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178909/my-school-wifi-asks-to-trust-a-certificate-on-iphones-does-it-this-allow-the), [Why would a school need to install certificates on student laptops?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/79555/) and [many many many more questions like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+certificate+school).

Comment: Somewhere on this page they mention that they're doing it for [SWI filtering](https://support.n4l.co.nz/s/article/Secure-Sockets-Layer-SSL-Inspection?ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.getRecord=1&r=58&ui-knowledge-components-aura-actions.KnowledgeArticleVersionCreateDraftFromOnlineAction.createDraftFromOnlineArticle=1).